# Unwanted click event on clones of button

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, clone, jquery-ui-dialog

[Edit]
Demo - http://jsbin.com/wedohawuyu/3/edit?output

Open blue label on the left and put button to the green div, dialog appears, put something in there and click button.
Drag next blue button the same way but change values in dialog. Click.

Now both buttons do the same action, why?

[/Edit]

I have menu with draggable buttons that I can put in sortable div. Draggables are set to clone. 
When u drop draggable in sortable div, dialog appears where you put some text in.

What I want to accomplish is to make evey button show diffrent text, but when I set 1st button to show 'qwe' and second to 'asd' both will show 'asd'.

Am I understanding wrong the idea of cloning, Im pretty new to jquery and js?

```
var dialogHeader, dialogContent, clone, dialog;

var strony = new Array;

$(".dropButton").droppable({
    accept: '.dragButton:not(".ui-sortable-helper")',
    drop : function(ev, ui) {
        clone = $(ui.draggable).clone().addClass("dropped");
        if(clone.hasClass("myBlueButtonDesign")){
            dialog.dialog('open');
        }//..rest is unnecessary I believe
};

dialog = $("#dialog").dialog({
     autoOpen: false,
     modal: true,
     width: 300,
     height: 400,
     buttons: [{
             text: 'Submit',
             click: function() {
                 submitInnerHtml(clone);
             }
         },
         {
             text: 'Cancel',
             click: function() {
                 dialog.dialog('close');
             }
     }]
 });

function submitInnerHtml(button) {
    strony[strony.length] = "<h1>" + dialogHeader.val() + "</h1><br/><p>" + dialogContent.val() + "</p>";
    button.click(function(){
        changeInner(strony.length - 1, "#workspaceNewsFeed", button);
    });
    dialog.dialog('close');
}

function changeInner(id, target, source) {
    $(target).html(strony[id]);
    var sourceName = $(source).find("p").text();
    $(".tekst").append(sourceName);
}
```

That is all you should need to help me out I believe. If you would need something more please request in comments.

HTML of menu where I drag from:

```
<div id="menu">
        <h3>Green</h3>
            <div>
                <div id="myGreenButton1" class="dragButton myGreenButtonDesign"><p>Button 1</p></div>
                <div id="myGreenButton2"  class="dragButton myGreenButtonDesign"><p>Button 2</p></div>
                <div id="myGreenButton3"  class="dragButton myGreenButtonDesign"><p>Button 3</p></div>
            </div>
        <h3>Red</h3>
            <div>
                <div id="myRedButton1"  class="dragButton myRedButtonDesign"><p>Button 1</p></div>
                <div id="myRedButton2"  class="dragButton myRedButtonDesign"><p>Button 2</p></div>
                <div id="myRedButton3"  class="dragButton myRedButtonDesign"><p>Button 3</p></div>
            </div>
        <h3>Blue</h3>
            <div>
                <div id="myBlueButton1"  class="dragButton myBlueButtonDesign"><p>Button 1</p></div>
                <div id="myBlueButton2"  class="dragButton myBlueButtonDesign"><p>Button 2</p></div>
                <div id="myBlueButton3"  class="dragButton myBlueButtonDesign"><p>Button 3</p></div>
            </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: try to give jsfiddle link...

Comment: @DevendraSoni added on top of post

Comment: Described the problem in [Edit][/Edit]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the answer to your question **why** it is showing last inserted value is because you are always using  `strony.length-1` in function call

```
changeInner(strony.length-1, "#workspaceNewsFeed", button);
```

so `strony.length-1` will point to last index of strony.

make it dynamic to pass current clicked button index otherwise it will always print the last.

get the index on button click so it will always point to clicked button stored value.

Comment: That is correct! I just find this out debugging and came here to write answer, but you were faster :)